# Simple SELECT query with calculated columns returns error

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a query:

```
use [Some_Database];
go
select toip 10 IDEVENT,
    COUNT(*)
from [AL_PROTOCOL]
    group by IDEVENT
    order by Quanity desc
go
```

In output I get results as

```
IDEVENT     Quanity
664         4,037787E+07
566         2,124254E+07
438         1,248467E+07
294         9926404 
564         9777449
436         5784661 
310         5709771 
428         5161083 
432         5154893 
434         5150308
```

So, then I try to calculate second `(*60 / 1,000,000)` column using `CONVERT (real (100), COUNT(*)*60/1000000, 2) as 'Size, Mb'`

next way:

```
use [Some_Database];
go
select top 10 IDEVENT,
    COUNT(*),
    CONVERT (real (100), COUNT(*)*60/1000000, 2) as 'Size, Mb'
from [AL_PROTOCOL]
    group by IDEVENT
    order by Quanity desc
go
```

After this, I get this error

> **8115 'Arithmetic overflow error converting *expression* to int type** 
>   **numeric**'.

Technet explains, that this kind of errors occurs when a value in the column is overgrowing the maximal size of integer type. But, why doesn't it  convert in REAL type?
Also, this question solved by replacing '*60/1,000,000' on '/1,000,000*60', but my interest is not satisfied.

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: @etsa, as I understand, in your example error does not occured then you manipulated value wich type doesn't defined yet. Then, it not INT type. If you modify youself query as next:

Comment: @esta SELECT CONVERT (real (100), Convert (int, 40377870000000 *60)/1000000, 2) as SIZE_MB , CONVERT (BIGINT, 4037787E+07 , 2) as N1

Comment: @esta, you get the same error 8115. See IMSoP answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully at the order of operations you have asked the DBMS to perform. `CONVERT (real (100), COUNT(*)*60/1000000, 2)` means:

1. `COUNT(*)`
2. `result * 60`
3. `result / 1000000`
4. `CONVERT (real (100), result, 2)`

Until step 4, the value is still an integer, so you get an overflow error if `COUNT(*) * 60` is higher than the maximum representable integer.

Because `*` and `/` have the same precedence, the workaround you found is `CONVERT (real (100), COUNT(*)/1000000*60, 2)`, which means:

1. `COUNT(*)`
2. `result / 1000000`
3. `result * 60`
4. `CONVERT (real (100), result, 2)`

We're still doing maths on integers, but now we never overflow because we divide before multiplying.

But what you actually wanted was to do all the maths on the floating point value:

1. `COUNT(*)`
2. `CONVERT (real (100), result, 2)`
3. `result * 60`
4. `result / 1000000`

For that, you just need to swap the nesting around so that you convert the `COUNT(*)` result directly, and then apply the maths: `CONVERT (real (100), COUNT(*), 2) * 60 / 1000000`

Comment: Really nice style in explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply a really large number by 60, you're going to get an even bigger number, increasing the chances of an arithmetic overflow. The fact that you divide it by 1,000,000 after is too late, you've already tried to generate a number that is too big to proceed with.

However, when you divide it by 1,000,000 first before multiplying by 60, then you are always going to get a smaller number, so you should never get an arithmetic overflow.

Also, with your `CONVERT`, you are doing it on the entire result, and all of the numbers in the calculation are of `INT` types, so it will generate an `INT` before the conversion.

```
COUNT(*)*60/1000000 -- COUNT(*) is an INT, as well as the other numbers
```

If you change the ordering of the `CONVERT` \ `CAST` it should work.

```
DECLARE @number AS INT 
SET @number = 123456789

-- this doesn't work
SELECT CAST((@number * 60) AS REAL(100))
-- this does
SELECT CAST(@number AS REAL(100)) * 60
```

Comment: Why result values in 'Size, MB' column calculates as INT, besides I define it  as REAL?